# Minimum value of modulus squares of sum of pairs of complex numbers

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

> If $z_1, z_2$ and $z_3$  are the three points lying on the circle $|z|=3$, the minimum value of $|z_1+z_2|^2 + |z_2 + z_3|^2 + |z_3 + z_1|^2$

The solution manual involves expanding this out:

$$ 2 \left[ |z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 + |z_3|^2\right] + z_1 \overline{z_2} + \overline{z_1} z_2 + z_2 \overline{z_3} + \overline{z_2} z_3 + \overline{z_3} z_1 + z_3 \overline{z_1} $$

Or by information in question,

$$ 2 \left[ 3 \cdot 3^2 \right] +  z_1 \overline{z_2} + \overline{z_1} z_2 + z_2 \overline{z_3} + \overline{z_2} z_3 + \overline{z_3} z_1 + z_3 \overline{z_1} \tag{1}  $$

Now for finding mininmum of:

$$ z_1 \overline{z_2} + \overline{z_1}z_2 + \overline{z_3} z_1 + \overline{z_1} z_3 + \overline{z_3} z_2 + z_2 \overline{z_3}$$

For finding it, the following inequality is used:

$$ |z_1 + z_2 + z_3|^2 \geq 0$$

ANd this expands:

$$  |z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 + |z_3|^2 + z_1 \overline{z_2} + \overline{z_1}z_2 + \overline{z_3} z_1 + \overline{z_1} z_3 + \overline{z_3} z_2 + z_2 \overline{z_3} \geq 0 $$

$$ z_1 \overline{z_2} + \overline{z_1}z_2 + \overline{z_3} z_1 + \overline{z_1} z_3 + \overline{z_3} z_2 + z_2 \overline{z_3} \geq -27 \tag{2}$$

But.. I don't get how this is the **minimum** value! What if we could find another inequality and get a lower bound? For example if we wrote the lower bound from(1):

$$ 2 \left[ 3 \cdot 3^2 \right] +  z_1 \overline{z_2} + \overline{z_1} z_2 + z_2 \overline{z_3} + \overline{z_2} z_3 + \overline{z_3} z_1 + z_3 \overline{z_1} \geq 0 $$

Or,

$$   z_1 \overline{z_2} + \overline{z_1} z_2 + z_2 \overline{z_3} + \overline{z_2} z_3 + \overline{z_3} z_1 + z_3 \overline{z_1} \geq -54 $$

Comment: The another inequality used does not yield the best minimum  as the simultaneous  equality case $|z_1=-z_2,z_2=-z_3,z_3=-z_1$ which isnt possible unless $z_i=0$ which violates $|z|=1$

Comment: I think you are right, the proof shows that the min of the function in $(2)$ is greater than or equal to $-27$.  But if you can find a single example of $z_1,z_2,z_3$ where the function in $(2)$ is equal to $-27$, that would complete the proof by showing that the min is less than or equal to $-27$.

Comment: I am syaing couldn't there possibly be a stronger lower bound which we don't know about @awkward

Comment: Wait sorry, what do you mean by simultaneous equality case @Albus Dumbeldore